# Time Complexity Of This Code Snippet

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Recently, I came across a code snippet:

```
int i = 1;
while (N > 1)
{
        N = N / i;
        i = i + 1;
}
```

On observation, it was evident that `i` increases linearly, and `i` divides `N` in every runtime of the loop, hence we could say that `N` reduces as a function of an **inverse function of a factorial.**

How would we represent this in the  **theta notation**, as **inverse factorial** is not defined for every natural number `N`? Would we have to suffice by using the approximate upper and lower bounds of this function?

Comment: What is the inverse factorial of 5? @FreeNickname

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misunderstood you. For some reason, I thought about 1/n! being an inverse factorial. I'll remove my comment now.

Comment: you could also try to ask this on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Tell them you come from a cs background. I found them to be very helpful. (just to be clear: I am **not** saying this is off topic here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure, but I'll give it a shot.
The factorial is, in essence, a [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). And gamma function is defined not only for natural numbers, but also for real numbers. So, there is, in theory, a inverse gamma function, which is defined for cases, where factorial is undefined (for instance, we don't know the inverse factorial of `5`, but we know, that the inverse gamma function of `5` will be something around two-point-something). According to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function), there is no precise formula for the inverse gamma function, but there are approximate solutions.

Let's just suppose that inverse gamma function exists, and let's write it as `InvGamma(N)`. It is an real number (might be R+, but I'm not sure, it's not important now, since our N is always positive, apart of N == 0 case, which I will ignore for now).

Then we can use it the same way as we use other functions that return a real number, when we deal with complexity: we can `floor` it (round it down). Just like we do with `log` complexity. I used to write using square brackets (i.e. `log(15) = 1.18`, `[log(15)] = 1`).

Then the complexity of your snippet should be `O([InvGamma(N)])`, I believe.

**UPDATE:** (inspired by @6502's answer): note that if `N` is an integer (it's not mentioned in the code snippet), then there will be a rounding on every step, which alters complexity in a complicated way. The solution above works for real `N`s.

Comment: The gamma inverse function is actually convincing. Thanks. The only shortcoming, though, is that it returns multiple values.

Comment: @ShauryaChats, Yes, indeed. The workaround would be to take the largest of values. Unfortunately, I'm not sure, what notation could be used to do it properly. I think, I would just leave it as it is. To my mind, it's clear what it means. And, for instance, `sqrt` also returns several values (a positive and a negative one), still it's being used in complexity functions simply as `O(sqrt(N))`.

Answer (score 1):

The "natural" extension of factorial to all complex plane except negative integers is called ["gamma function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and on all non-negative integers `gamma(n) = (n-1)!`.

You could therefore invert a portion of gamma to compute the approximate number of iterations needed but I'm not sure this would lead to an **exact** computation of the number of iterations as in that code there is a rounding operation at every step.

Comment: Good point about rounding operation on every step. We don't know the type of `N` though. But I agree, that it most likely is an `integer` of some kind.

Comment: @FreeNickname Floating point arithmetic also leads to rounding!

Comment: @Rerito, yes, it does, but floating point arithmetics rounding is usually ignored in case of complexity calculations, because we wouldn't be able to calculate the complexity of half of algorithms otherwise.